# What subject pronoun is proper to use for "anybody or anyone" in the below sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> If anyone/anybody clicks on it, they/he/she/it will become your referral.

And is that possible to build this sentence without referring to any subject?

Comment: It is. You could write "Whoever clicks on it becomes your referral." Doing this keeps the subject/verb agreement and keeps you safe.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. But note that you don't ***have*** to choose between ***they/he/she/it*** here, if you rephrase to *Anyone/Anybody **who** clicks on it will become your referral*. but if you ***are*** going to use a pronoun, only ***they / he / she*** are acceptable (your choice) - you ***can't*** normally use ***it*** to refer to people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question means, but I will make a few comments.

1. There is no significant difference between "anyone" and "anybody." It is pointless to offer both of them as options.
2. English never refers to people as "it," so that option can be removed.
3. If you feel brave, consider using "they" without "he" or "she." It is the norm in speech, and many style guides now recommend its use as a genderless pronoun in writing. Thus:

> If anyone clicks on it, they will become your referral.

But take note that this usage is still controversial. Traditionally, the male pronoun has been used in generic situations. For much of the 20th century, the recommended usage was to follow "one" or "anyone" with ""he or she." Many traditionalists insist that "they" must always have a plural meaning. Consider your audience.

4. For this sentence, the best revision might be this:

> Anyone who clicks on it will become your referral.

Comment: I don't know why the answer was down-voted. All the points are valid, and it's also true there are probably people who don't like using the singular _they_.

Comment: Good answer (upvoted), except I'd specify that the traditionalists will complain that "they" is always plural, and the correct choice of pronoun is either "he" or "he or she" if you don't know the gender.